# What does the dash/minus sign in the 'Allow executing file as program' checkbox indicate?

Tags: nautilus

When I click on this checkbox to make a script that I downloaded executable, the first time I click it the box shows a half-filled/hyphen icon. If I click it again, it looks like a normal check mark. What is the difference between the two states?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execute bit can be set for: Owner, Group, Others

If the execute bit is set but not for all of them Nautilus displays a dash in the check box.

chmod 544 filename

Results in permissions (-r-xr--r--)